# Counting the occurrences of a sequence of events spread over multiple rows

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

So the table holds a time sequential record of events like so:

```
+-------------------------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
|        Timestamp        |   id   | event  | variable 1 | variable 2 |
+-------------------------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| 2019-05-17 00:00:00.000 | abc123 | event1 | variable1  | null       |
| 2019-05-17 00:00:10.000 | abc123 | event2 | null       | variable2  |
| 2019-05-17 00:00:15.000 | abc123 | event3 | null       | null       |
| 2019-05-17 00:05:00.000 | abc123 | event1 | variable1  | null       |
| 2019-05-17 00:05:10.000 | abc123 | event4 | null       | null       |
| 2019-05-17 00:05:15.000 | abc123 | event3 | null       | null       |
+-------------------------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
```

The requirement is to count the number of times a specific sequence of events occurs e.g. `event1` follows to `event2` which follows to `event3`. So in the above example the code would return:

```
+--------+----------------+
|   id   | sequence_count |
+--------+----------------+
| abc123 |              1 |
+--------+----------------+
```

The `event1` -> `event2` ->`event3` sequence occurred once in the data set for user `abc123`, `event1` -> `event4` ->`event3` sequence is not counted. The variable used to cut the count could also be switched to give the result:

```
+------------+----------------+
| variable 1 | sequence_count |
+------------+----------------+
| variable1  |              1 |
+------------+----------------+
```

For the purposes of this query, the timestamp variable should be treated as ordinal, not cardinal. I honestly have no idea where to start for this, if someone could help with the basis for this type of query I should be able to build it to extract the other insights I want from the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `LEAD()` analytic function, as in:

```
with
x as (
  select
    event,
    lead(event) over(order by timestamp) as next_event,
    lead(event, 2) over(order by timestamp) as next_next_event
  from t
)
select count(*)
from x
where event = 'event1'
  and next_event = 'event2'
  and next_next_event = 'event3'
```

**Added**:

I'm not quite sure about the additional question you asked in the comments, but it seems to me you want to group by *initiating variable*. If that's the case, you could do:

```
with
x as (
  select
    event,
    variable_1,
    lead(event) over(order by timestamp) as next_event,
    lead(event, 2) over(order by timestamp) as next_next_event
  from t
)
select variable_1, count(*)
from x
where event = 'event1'
  and next_event = 'event2'
  and next_next_event = 'event3'
group by variable_1
```

Comment: I think this works fine, how would you suggest mapping the combination of sequences if I didn't know the specific events? E.g. event1->event2->eventx; where I want to find the different values of x and their counts as yielded by your query above?

Comment: @AJG Added an extra query. I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm wondering how one would approach this solution if there were potentially multiple events between records. That would prevent the LEAD([field], [row offset count]) approach from working. I'm trying to solve something similar, but there is an unknown number of rows between the events, and the sequence is unknown.

Comment: @psrpsrpsr Should the "unknown rows between events" be ignored? How you determine which rows to ignore? If you need an answer ask the question with some representative rows of data and the expected result. Seems to me the solution shouldn't be that complex.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know bigquery,  but the following is just some ideas. You should know the start event, e.g. 'event1'.

```
WITH cteSt (rid,id,timestamp)
AS
(
  -- Get all the timestamp for the start event
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp), id, timestamp 
  FROM dataset 
  WHERE event='event1' -- start event
),
cteRange(id,start_ts,end_ts)
AS
(
  -- get previous time stamp as end ts for comparing
  SELECT s.id,s.timestamp,COALESCE(e.timestamp,current_ts)
  FROM cteSt s
  LEFT JOIN cteSt e
  ON s.id=e.id
  AND s.rid+1=e.rid
),
cte_Events(id, start_ts, event_sequence)
AS
(
  -- event sequence order by ts
  SELECT r.id,r.start_ts, GROUP_CONCAT(d.event ORDER BY d.timestamp SEPARATOR ',')
  FROM cteRange r
  INNER JOIN dataset d
  ON r.id=d.id
  AND d.timestamp BETWEEN r.start_ts AND r.end_ts
  GROUP BY r.id,r.start_ts
)
-- get the occurrences for each event sequence
SELECT id,event_sequence,COUNT(*) AS occurrences
FROM cte_Events
WHERE event_sequence='YourSequence' -- or get all sequence count without where
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, 
  ARRAY_LENGTH(
    REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(
      CONCAT(',', STRING_AGG(event ORDER BY Timestamp)), 
      ',event1,event2,event3')
  ) AS sequence_count
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id
```